# Finding chords that match with single notes

Tags: learning, chords

I just heard [Lenka's "Everything at Once"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zMbB3TzuPc).

The Background chord progression is quite catchy. I tried to figure out its chords, but to no avail.

I tried singular notes: I found `F A C A` and also `C E G. E` (where G is down an octave).

How do I find Chords that match up with single notes?

And what are they called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the chord for a single note](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/finding-the-chord-for-a-single-note)

Comment: The chords used in the song are Dm, C, A, and Bb (in order of how often they occur). You'll have to figure out where/when each is used yourself as a homework assignment. :-)

Comment: Strangely enough, I don't find this to be a dupe of that other question. Rather, I think the titles actually need to be switched -- that question is about finding chords that actually sound like a single note (i.e. Power Chords) whereas this song's chords are quite clearly not power chords.

Comment: Much more similar to [Is it possible to find the correct chords from melody notes alone?](http://music.stackexchange.com/q/5348/133), though still not quite.

Answer (score 2):

As I listen to the song, I don't really hear any tonality change. In such cases, the [circle of Fifths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_fifths) is you forever ally.

Around a tonality, there are five chord positions that instinctively sound good. You guess them with that circle.

With the notes like c,g,e,a,f... you're probably in C Major or A minor(both are instrincally linked), so you can go easily to G major, E minor, F major, D minor.

Answer (score 2):

Without actually listening to the song, there are a few facts you might not be aware of, misconceptions about which could easily lead to the qustion you ask.

The whole point of a chord is the several note blend together and become unified, united. The notes *sound as one*. On an equal-tempered instrument (piano, guitar, etc) most of the intervals are actually just a little bit *out-of-tune* with each other. This results in the individual notes becoming more distinct: it's easier to identify the separate notes that compose the chord.

With other tuning systems (Just tuning, Helmholtz tunings) the blending effect can be intensified so many notes unite into a sonic pattern from which the separate notes are very difficult to *pick out*. With the explosion of computers and digital synthesizers, this territory has been opened-up for colonization.

Often the strongest note you hear (the "melody" of the chords) will be a third or a fifth rather than the root due the effects of "voice leading" or *counterpoint*.

When you're trying to *figure out the chords* to a song, 99% of the time you should try to listen for the "bass-line" and ignore everything else. The bass may not play the roots of all the chords; but 99% of the time it will play the root every time the tonic (the *Key* chord) comes around.